# When i remove DispatchQueue.main.async I get no error

Tags: swift, request, queue, completionhandler

so we have this code
it makes a request to get data from API, I have learned that updating UI should only be on main thread but If I remove DispatchQueue.main.async {} nothing happens, no error or no warning
so I want to know should I keep it or not

```
func loadUsers() {
        server.getUserInfo()
        server.completionHandler {[weak self] (users,status,message) in
            if status {
                guard self != nil else {return}
                guard users != nil else {
                    return
                }
                self?.userViewModel.setUsers(users: users!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no error (now, it's a purple ruban on that line and maybe an error in console, or a breakpoint if the setting is enabled), it means that `ompletionHandler` has been called in main thread. Be carefull, sometimes the closure can be called in current thread, and sometimes not.

Comment: @Larme yes i printed out current thread and it says main, but It is not like that always right?

Comment: There is not guarantee as such. The call that will trigger it can be in any thread. It depends on how it's done. What's the doc of `completionHandler` Is it your code? If so, which one is it? Its docs guarantee a special thread?

Comment: @Larme I am using alamofire request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using an alamofire request in my project

```
AF.request(TodoRouter.getData(parameters: parameters)).responseJSON
```

and the response JSON method takes a queue and if you do not specify it the default is main